# total unique elements after doing groupby using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to get total count of unique elements post doing group by

Example Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'x', 'x','x','y']
                , 'B': ['a', 'c', 'c','b','e']
                , 'C': ['1', '2', '2','3','4']})

    A   B   C
0   x   a   1
1   x   c   2
2   x   c   2
3   x   b   3
4   y   e   4
```

I have tried below but none is giving me expected results

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).count()
df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].nunique()
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({"B": "sum"})
```

Expected output
X : 3  ( unique values were a, b, c)
Y : 1  (unique values was e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by A then count unique of B

```
df.groupby('A').B.nunique()
```